# create jquery array from c# object MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have model with dates and value, which I need to inject into the page so the Jquery can render the chart correctly.

Any suggestions?
I want to bind json from the controller to the chart script below to map year, int value.
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html

```
var line1 = [
      ['2014-01-01 12:00PM', 0], 
      ['2015-01-01 12:00PM', 242171], 
      ['2016-01-01 12:00PM', 392455], 
      ['2017-01-01 12:00PM', 498840], 
      ['2018-01-01 12:00PM', 577278], 
      ['2019-01-01 12:00PM', 635715], 
      ['2020-01-01 12:00PM', 678891], 
      ['2021-01-01 12:00PM', 709949], 
      ['2022-01-01 12:00PM', 731114], 
      ['2023-01-01 12:00PM', 744040], 
      ['2024-01-01 12:00PM', 750000]
 ];
```

Got my answer:
For Json reposne of {"2014":345234,"2015":530800,"2016":640193,"2017":701163,"2018":727528}

```
    $(document).ready(function () {                
        $.getJSON("quote/GetChartLine", function (data) {
            var arr = [];
            //Data would be your array
            for (var i in data) {
                arr.push([i, data[i]]);
            }                
        var line1 = [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]];                
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [arr], {
            title: 'Earnings Vs Investment',
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%b %Y'
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: 'Rs %.2f'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            },

            series: [{ lineWidth: 3, color: 'green', markerOptions: { color: 'green' } }, { lineWidth: 3, color: 'maroon', markerOptions: { color: 'maroon' } }]
        });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you using MVC? I mean MVC or WebForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Please note to run dates you must add one more lib.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart1"></div>
        <script>
            var obj = { "01-01-2014": 544, "01-01-2015": 753, "01-01-2016": 834 };
            var arr = [];
            for (var i in obj) {
                arr.push([i, obj[i]]);
            }

            var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [arr], {
                title: 'Default Date Axis',
                axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer } },
                series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

To parse multi obj

```
var arr = [];
for (var i in obj) {
 var sub = [];
 for (var j in i){
    sub.push([j, i[j]]);
 }
 arr.push(sub);
}
```

and jqPlot

```
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', arr, {
```

PS: please note now arr is without [] since its already as jqplot require

Comment: I am getting the data in json format but finding issues transforming it into jquery array. the json I am spitting out from controller is {"01-01-2014":544,"01-01-2015":753,"01-01-2016":834}   but how do I convert into jquery array. this where its failing

Comment: Sorry for not giving you the entire question in the first place. I am trying to bind the json return from controller to the chart script here http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html. My intention is to plot [Year, Double]

Comment: Can you modify server side? if yes then try to return List<KeyValuePair<Date, double>> and it will work, also pay attention that to make it work you need to pause multy array, [[And your data here]] since its possible to bind multiple axis

Comment: @user3173632 Hope now its what you need :) b

Comment: I am returing 3 lines in the json, would you please show me how this can be done too?  [{"2014":345234,"2015":530800,"2016":640193,"2017":701163,"2018":727528},{"2014":28769,"2015":15464,"2016":9116,"2017":5081,"2018":2197},{"2014":159668,"2015":152347,"2016":145266,"2017":138425,"2018":131821}]

Comment: I tried the one above which for some reason didnt work. from you nested loop I got the idea and I just went with this and it worked.I am using this as I know I am only going to have 3 lines for the chart.

Comment: for (var i in data[0]) {
                        console.log(i);
                        for (var j in data[0]) {
                            line1.push([j, data[0][i]]);
                        }                        
                    }
                    for (var i in data[1]) {
                        for (var j in data[1]) {
                            line2.push([j, data[1][i]]);
                        }
                    }

Comment: for (var i in data[2]) {
                        for (var j in data[2]) {
                            line3.push([j, data[2][i]]);
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 0):

In action you need to return your object with help of [`Controller.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method. Let's say you are getting a list of dates and some other data from `_someService.GetSomeData()` method inside of `SomeActionMethod` action in `SomeCntrlController`. It'll look like this:

```
public partial class SomeCntrlController : Controller
{
public JsonResult SomeActionMethod() {
var result = _someService.GetSomeData();
            return Json(new { success = true, result = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

And here's how you'll retrieve data in your JScript using jQuery:

```
var res = '';
$.getJSON('/SomeCntrlController/SomeActionMethod',
                        function(data) {
                            if (data.success) {
                   res = data.result; // your data from server in Json format
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the System.Web.Extensions assembly:

```
    var data = line1Data.Select(x => 
        new object[] { String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", x.Date), x.Value });

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
```